# Velocity Controller for Kuka Robot

Tags: controller, drake

I'm trying to make my Kuka end effector go to a desired goal using a control Lyapunov function. I'm following this paper: http://skrifo.juxi.net/papers/zhuang2019iros.pdf

The Lyapunov function is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WgXv.png), and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANdxO.png) is its partial derivatives wrt the joint angles.

So far, the controller seems to be doing some wacky things--the Lyapunov function doesn't seem to be decreasing at all time steps [`assert(V <= prev_V + 0.001)` fails!]. The Lyapunov function seems right, but I think the issue comes from calculating the partial derivatives. The Jacobian calculation makes sense in my head (I want the output to be in the end effector frame), but something seems clearly wrong:

```
jacobian = robot.CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity(
    context=differential_ik.GetRobotContext(), with_respect_to=JacobianWrtVariable.kQDot,
    frame_B=robot.world_frame(),                    # frame on which point Bi is fixed
    p_BP=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],                           # position vec from frame_B's origin to points Bi
    frame_A=robot.GetFrameByName("iiwa_link_7"),    # frame that measures v_ABi
    frame_E=robot.GetFrameByName("iiwa_link_7"))    # frame that v_ABi is expressed on input 
                                                    # and frame that Jacobian J_V_ABi is expressed on output
```

[I added `GetRobotContext()` to the `DifferentialIK` class but could have used `GetSubsystemContext()`]

I'm setting the velocity in Drake with `q = q_prev + time_step * q_dot` and then `differential_ik.SetPositions()` on `q`.

Here is the smallest working code I could create to replicate my issue (sorry it's still kind of large): https://gist.github.com/maggi3wang/1cbb02a0adc2cec85915f856ab3d1702#file-small_collect_data-py-L174

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the quickest approach to debug your program is to check if `∂V / ∂θ` is computed correctly (which I believe is the variable `pdV` in your code). You could compute this gradient through numerical difference, and then compare the numerical gradient with your gradient.

I tried to derive the control law below:

Say you want your ᵂX⁷ ∈ SE(3) (pose of link 7 measured and expressed in the world frame) to match with some desired pose ᵂX⁷_des, and you define your Lyapunov function as

```
V = |ᵂX⁷ - ᵂX⁷_des|_F
```

where I use `| |_F` to denote the Frobenius norm. I will use `ᵂR⁷` to denote the rotation matrix, and `ᵂp⁷` to denote the position of link 7 in the world frame.

This Lyapunov function is equivalent to

```
V = |ᵂR⁷ - ᵂR⁷_des|_F + (ᵂp⁷ - ᵂp⁷_des)ᵀ(ᵂp⁷ - ᵂp⁷_des)
  = trace((ᵂR⁷ - ᵂR⁷_des)ᵀ(ᵂR⁷ - ᵂR⁷_des)) + (ᵂp⁷ - ᵂp⁷_des)ᵀ(ᵂp⁷ - ᵂp⁷_des)
  = 6 - 2*trace(ᵂR⁷_desᵀ * ᵂR⁷) + (ᵂp⁷ - ᵂp⁷_des)ᵀ(ᵂp⁷ - ᵂp⁷_des)
```

Your goal is to compute the gradient `∂V / ∂θ`. To compute this partial derivative, you need the partial derivative `∂ᵂR⁷ / ∂θ` and `∂ᵂp⁷ / ∂θ`. When you compute the Jacobian from `CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity`, the translational part of this Jacobian is `∂⁷pᵂ / ∂θ` (BTW I am more used to express the position/velocity in world frame instead of link 7's frame), but the rotational part of this Jacobian is **not** `∂ᵂR⁷ / ∂θ`. Suppose you called

```
jacobian = robot.CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity(
    context=differential_ik.GetRobotContext(), with_respect_to=JacobianWrtVariable.kQDot,
    frame_B=robot.GetFrameByName("iiwa_link_7"),
    p_BP=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    frame_A=robot.world_frame(),
    frame_E=robot.world_frame())
```

, the rotational part of this Jacobian is `∂ ᵂω⁷/∂ θ_dot`, where `ᵂω⁷` is the angular velocity of link 7 measured and expressed in the world frame. In order to compute `∂ᵂR⁷ / ∂θ`, we use the following equation

```
∂ᵂR⁷ / ∂θ = ∂ᵂR_dot⁷ / ∂θ_dot
          = ∂(⌊ᵂω⁷⌋ₓ ᵂR⁷) / ∂θ_dot
          = (∂⌊ᵂω⁷⌋ₓ / ∂θ_dot ) * ᵂR⁷
```

in the first line of the equation, I took time derivative of both the numerator and the denominator. In the second line of the equation, I use the equation `ᵂR_dot⁷ = ⌊ᵂω⁷⌋ₓ ᵂR⁷`, where `⌊ᵂω⁷⌋ₓ` represent the skew-symmetric matrix of the angular velocity `ᵂω⁷` (BTW, I forgot if it is `ᵂR_dot⁷ = ⌊ᵂω⁷⌋ₓ ᵂR⁷` or `ᵂR_dot⁷ =  ᵂR⁷⌊ᵂω⁷⌋ₓ`. If one doesn't work, you could try the other) The last line of the equation holds by taking the gradient of a product, and `∂ᵂR⁷ / ∂θ_dot = 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your clear post! I changed my formulation to be in the world frame and computed ∂ᵂR⁷ / ∂θ as you described. However, V still doesn't decrease at all time steps. 
To your point on computing the gradient using numerical difference to approximate ∂V / ∂θ [using something like (V(x+theta_i) - V(x))/ theta_i for all joint angles]--how would I get the small changes in theta and V(x+theta_i)?

Comment: I would write a function `compute_V(theta)` to compute V(θ) = |ᵂX⁷(θ) - ᵂX⁷_des|_F. You could compute ᵂX⁷(θ) using the function MultibodyPlant::CalcRelativeTransform(). And then I will perturb each θᵢ by a small amount (around 1e-7) and evaluate V again with this perturbed θ (BTW I recommend using central difference as opposed to forward or backward difference for better numerical accuracy).

Also note that since you compute `V` in every dt, it doesn't guarantee that V always decrease (V is guaranteed to decrease only with very small time steps).

Comment: BTW, I think the `mu` in your code is probably too large. You could try a smaller `mu`. The algorithm is basically doing gradient descent, and using `mu` as the step size. Gradient descent only guarantees reducing the cost if the step size is small. With large step size, gradient descent "overshoot" and can increase the cost.

Comment: Sweet, the numerical gradient and the gradient seem to match. Lowering `mu` makes it run almost unbearably slow. I'll see if it's more accurate, though.

Comment: Tuning `mu` and `M` (now just a weight for the translational part of the Jacobian) makes the controller work pretty well for various initial goals and end effector poses. Thanks so much for your help!